# Java replaceAll with new lines in regex

Tags: java, regex, file, replaceall

I want to replace text "`1\n2`" ("1" new line and "2")with for example "`abcd`". I've been searching a lot for solution but I can't find.

Below is my code

```
String REGEX = "1\n2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
String newText = m.replaceAll("abcd");
```

[EDIT]
I'd like to add that text variable is read from file:

```
String text = new Scanner(new File("...")).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

Comment: You should [escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html) the \.

Comment: Not working. When it's tabulator "1\t2" or "1\\t2" it works.

Comment: @user1411881  can you please paste the string which you are trying to modify ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your regex to

```
String REGEX = "1\\n2";
```

So it escapes the `\n`

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String REGEX = "1\n2";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher("test1\n2test");
    String newText = m.replaceAll("abcd");
    System.out.println(newText);
}
```

**O/P:**

```
testabcdtest
```

Or even simply

```
String newText = "test1\n2test".replaceAll("1\n2", "abcd");
```

**O/P**

```
testabcdtest
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regex for this? Just use

```
String newText = text.replace("1\n2", "abcd");
```

Comment: Then your text doesn't contain "1\n2". Maybe it contains "1\r\n2"?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String str="Your String"
str=str.replace("1\n2","abc");
```